# Find the boundary of a polygon (or a staircase) c++

Tags: c++, rectangles

I'm doing an 2D bin packing algorithm. The goal is to put a set of rectangle into a bin one by one.

At each rectangle insertion, i want to update the boundary between occupied area and free area. Thus, i'm looking for an algorithm or the way to do it. Algorithm must be able to:

1) Find the boundary after rectangle insertion (or find all points of the boundary).

2) Travel clockwise all the points of the boundary (imagine that now I have all points coordinates of the boundary).

3) At each corner (point) of the boundary, the algorithm can determinate if this point is on the top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information, just ask and I'll provide all I can.

Thank you

Comment: this seems homework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

[How is 2D bin packing achieved programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762569/how-is-2d-bin-packing-achieved-programmatically)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352575/2d-bin-packing-problem-with-opportunity-to-optimize-the-size-of-the-bin