# algorithm for finding least area occupied with n rectangulars

Tags: algorithm, bin-packing

I have a number of rectangular, I want to find the smallest rectangular which can cover all small ones. no rotation is allowed.
[image]

Using brute force I want to find my answer. I am trying to code it in java.
I know I should check all permutation of my n items and find the least area. And in order to make it easier first I tried to find min possible area. Then I used a 2 dimensional array with Boolean values to check if each cell is occupied or not.  But I could not figure it out (code it).

How to check if my items can be placed in my limited area? For example I located my first item in `x[0][0]` to `x[10][1]` and make all cell in this range true, but I don't know how to tell my program to check other cell for next item. Can you tell me about steps which my algorithm need to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Your problems falls under the category of 2D-bin packing. It is an NP-hard problem, so there doesn't exist an efficient polynomial time algorithm for solving it. (Unless P==NP).

You could either try Brute force algorithm or clever heuristics which will give you fairly optimal solution.

Refer the following links:
1.  [How is 2D bin packing achieved programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762569/how-is-2d-bin-packing-achieved-programmatically) (For discussing various algorithms)
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu (For implementation details)
3. http://www.binpacking.4fan.cz/ (for visualizing different heuristics)

---

Your brute force algorithm is very inefficient. The permutation in which the rectangles can be placed are very huge and difficult to find. I suggest you try above mentioned algorithms, which are easier to implement than finding going to all permutations.