# How to spread boxes on into another box in non-iterative manner?

Tags: algorithm, math, packing, analytical

So I have boxes of different sizes (squares). I have a Big Box (not a square). I have no guarantee that all of my boxes will fit, yet I need to try to fit as much as possible in a non-iterative manner without overlap. What algorithm allows for such non-iterative a box packing?

Comment: "polygon shape that looks like a doughnut" is it a convex? A regular convex? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: A doughnut is a 3D object (torus), so how does that describe a polygon?

Comment: Are you optimising the area or the number of shapes?

Comment: Simplified the question and added details.

Comment: What does non-iterative mean? No loops? Or just no guess-and-check brute-force?

Comment: @Patrick87: just no guess-and-check brute-force

Comment: Isn't this now just about *2D bin packing* ?   I don't think the Internet, nor even Stack Overflow, needs another explanation of that.

Comment: Any algorithm will need to iterate over the input list of boxes. There is no non-iterative algorithm

Comment: I think there should be a note, that if the sum of certain boxes' areas is less than the area of the Big Box, that doesn't mean they can fit into it.

Comment: "as much as possible" is also not so clear. Do you want to occupy the maximum possible volume or to fit the highest possible number of boxes  ? i.e. It is best to put one big box or 10 smaller boxes with the same cumulative volume ?

Comment: What have you tried? and why didn't they work for you?

Comment: Did you look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762569/how-is-2d-bin-packing-achieved-programmatically. It's at least similar.

Comment: I suspect the OP actually means "non recursive".

Comment: @DuckQueen Is the Big Box a polygon? Is it convex? Can you rotate the boxes (e.g. to fit against an edge of the Big Box)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is it [Bin Packing Algorithm](https://codeincomplete.com/posts/bin-packing/), [demo](https://codeincomplete.com/posts/bin-packing/demo/), start from biggets to lowest size and try search for the place.